# How does numpy's equality operator between arrays result in more arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Consider the following:

```
>>> (np.arange(10) == [[0], [5], [4]]).astype(float)
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

I understand the effect - the result is an array of arrays of size `10` (the size given to `arange`) where each array corresponding to the array in the second array of arrays has a `True` for that corresponding index. The `.astype(float)` is to convert it all to float, which I did here for ease of readability.

But what is the underlying logic behind the operator? I'm new to numpy and so the above simply looks like black magic. Further, when i try to experiment with it, I get results that are unexpected to me. For example, what if I want two values set to `1.`? This doesn't work:

```
>>> (np.arange(10) == [[0, 2], [5], [4]])
False
>>> (np.arange(10) == [[0, 2], [5, 1], [4, 2]])
False
```

Instead of an array as a result, I get a boolean.

I also wonder why it doesn't do the same thing for a single list:

```
>>> (np.arange(10) == [0, 5, 4])
False
```

Yet for a one-element list, it works:

```
>>> (np.arange(10) == [4]).astype(float)
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
```

Finally, it does something interesting if I give it a list of list of lists instead:

```
>>> (np.arange(10) == [[[0]], [[5]], [[4]]]).astype(float)
array([[[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]]])
```

What's the logic behind these examples? When can I expect an array as a result, vs. a boolean?

Comment: `np.arange(10) == [4]` should have given you an array of booleans.

Comment: @user2357112: ahhh now that is interesting! i believe i can piece it together now. It returns an array matching the dimensions of the larger array, where each element is whether that element equals the element provided in the one-element array. For a list of list of these, it just does this repeatedly.

Answer (score 1):

The magic word here is *broadcasting*. Rather than explain it here myself, let me refer you to [this article](http://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/EricsBroadcastingDoc) with nice illustrations (linked to from the [numpy documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) itself).

Answer (score 1):

```
np.arange(10) == [[0], [5], [4]]
```

`np.array([[0], [5], [4]])` is (3,1) shape; `np.arange(10)` is `(10,)` which can expand to (1,10).  The result is (3,10)

`np.array([[0, 2], [5], [4]])` is a (3,) object array, because the sublists differ in size.  (3,) is not the same as (10,), hence False - sizes don't match

`[[0, 2], [5, 1], [4, 2]]` produces a (3,2) array; again no match.

In general, check the shape of each array and its dtype.  Apply the broadcasting rules if possible.

In some cases it may be easier to see what is happening with plain addition

```
np.arange(10)+np.arange(3).reshape(3,1)
```

What is?

```
np.array([[[0]], [[5]], [[4]]]).shape
```

(3,1,1)!

```
In [1160]: np.array([[[0]], [[5]], [[4]]])+np.arange(10)
Out[1160]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9]],

       [[ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]],

       [[ 4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13]]])

In [1161]: _.shape
Out[1161]: (3, 1, 10)
```

`(3,1,1) + (1,1,10)`